# Linux command-line C compilers for PIC10F200

Tags: microcontroller, pic, linux, compiler, pickit

What I have

- a Raspberry Pi with Raspberry Pi OS Lite 32-bit (a port of Debian with no desktop) environment installed
- PIC10F200 microcontrollers
- a [PICKit3-like programmer](https://www.amazon.nl/gp/product/B07DJ5PBSX/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

I want to compile C and upload it to the microcontroller, hopefully replicating [these series of tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvsLWEJ4kNI). What I have found so far:

- There is the [Small Device C Compiler (SDCC)](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net) for which I have found [this nice tutorial](https://hackaday.com/2010/11/03/how-to-program-pics-using-linux/). However, it doesn't seem to support the PIC10 series.
- The official Microchip's MPLAB XC8 compiler. But I have no idea if/how it can be installed on my OS and if it has a non-GUI (only command-line) version?
- There seem to be other options such as [CPIK](http://pikdev.free.fr/download-cpik.php3), PicCBuilder, [GPUTILS](https://gputils.sourceforge.io), [GNUPIC](http://www.gnupic.dds.nl)... but I honestly don't know what they are and if they suit the propose I'm looking for.

Things I think I need are:

- A C compiler (like gcc-avr)
- An assembler (like avra)
- A programmer (like avrdude)

I would appreciate it if you could help me know how/if I can use the above environment to program my PIC10 microcontroller.

**P.S.** More C compilers have been listed [here](http://jmandon.free.fr/choisir/choisir.htm) and [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/82110/23264).

Comment: Foad, I clicked on "Documentation" on the MPLAB XC8 product page on microchip.com; there I was taken to a list where I clicked on "MPLAB XC8 C Compiler User Guide for PIC MCUs", and that document has a section "How Do I Compile on the Command-line?" https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tools-tools-and-software/mplab-xc-compilers#Documentation

Comment: @MarcusMüller can you be kind to share the link?

Comment: Furthermore, let's be honest: if you want to learn how to program microcontrollers, *please* don't start with a PIC10. You get not even 400 B of RAM, and your stack is literally two deep – that's not what you'd want to learn or teach today; for the same price, some other MCUs can be had, which do have better support for C – yes, you can compile C for running on an PIC10, but that device really hasn't got the things that makes C acceptable.

Comment: @MarcusMüller this is not a professional activity but some sort of geeky meditation for me. Challenging myself in uncharted territories so I can keep my mind away from stresses. Of course from professional and practical point of view I should go a different way...

Comment: @MarcusMüller BTW I don't mind writing in Assembly either, if we have an assembler and a programmer for my environment.

Comment: I rummaged around a bit on Microchip's site, but it doesn't [look like](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tools-tools-and-software/mplab-xc-compilers#tabs) the XC8 compiler is available for ARM. They don't even seem to make x86-64 builds.

Comment: @marcelm that's probably true, but that piece of software is so little and building software for a 400B MCU is so trivial computationally that running the compiler itself on qemu-user [should be straightforward](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation). (yes, you can in this day and age run software compiled for a completely different processor as if the machine was something else, and Qemu translates the system calls. It's mind-boggling.)

Comment: @Foad I mean, it's your hobby, so I can't really argue, but I think if you're looking for a challenge, you'll quickly find the device sets you very harsh limits when you try to use it with C; but here's an idea: You already have a RPi, which should be a functional superset of the PIC10 in every way. So, what 'bout this challenge:  Learn how to take a hardware definition of a small CPU which is supported by GCC, and convert that into a working simulation of the CPU. Then, learn how to use GCC to target that, and finally make your RPi a simulated small microcontroller, just for shits'n'giggles.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Fair enough, I hadn't thought of that :) I agree performance shouldn't be a show-stopper for this scenario.

Comment: @marcelm thanks for the kind words, but you're still very right: this is very overcomplicating everything: trying to compile a language that it barely supports for an obsolete microcontroller on an embedded platform on which the target vendor's toolchain doesn't run natively...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well, if it helps Foad achieve Zen :)

Comment: @marcelm absolutely!

Comment: folks, check my pseudo-answer below.

Comment: Try the Microchip tools under Wine and report back.  TL;DR -- they may or may not work.  But they'll never work if you never try.

Comment: @TimWescott can I run Wine on a headless ARM Linux?

Comment: You want to write C for a PIC on headless ARM Linux?

Answer (score 4):

C is probably a non starter, the PIC10 core really isn't designed for that.

I few years ago I got some pic10s and successfully managed to make an LED blinker using the linux `gputils` tools and a `Pickit II` compatible programmer.  the code was in pic assembler.

Comment: the gputils software package doesn't include a programmer, AFIK. Didn't you use PK2CMD?

Comment: I found all the software that I needed in debian, so I suspect that I used `ponyprog`

Comment: I think PonyProg doesn't support PIC10, does it? 

Comment: I don't recall, I just found PK2CMD compiled from source (in january 2013), perhaps I did use that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question but a list of things I have figured out so far:

- There is [picprog](https://hyvatti.fi/%7Ejaakko/pic/picprog.html) which sadly doesn't support the PIC10 microcontrollers. I have found a fork called [ugly-pic-programmer (upicprog)](https://sites.google.com/site/upicprog/) by
  Marek Blaszkowski that should support PIC10.
- There is PK2CMD Open Source but not Free/Libre programmer originally distributed by Microchip but deprecated. The source code is available on the internet, for example [here](https://github.com/psmay/pk2cmd). One can compile it manually but I'm not quite sure how the libusb dependency needs to be installed. Apparently it is not compatible with the PIKit3-like programmer I have but good news is that one can program PIC10F200 according to [this tutorial](http://www.thomasjenkins.net/tinkering/guides/10F200.html).
- There are `gpasm` and `gplink` assembler and linker part of the [gputils package](https://gputils.sourceforge.io). And they do support PIC10 microcontrollers.

**P.S.** From [here](https://curuxa.org/en/Pk2cmd_manual_installation), one can install `sudo apt install libusb-dev`

Comment: well, if you need to build yet another programmer to program the MCU you have: have you considered using a different target MCU just to get your feet off the ground (you can then build a programmer with that, if you want to!)? Something like the ~14€ ST Nucleo boards are very nice, they come with a detacheable programmer and a target board, and you can start right away with software you can probably directly install via `apt` (haven't tried it on debian, but on Fedora on x86_64 and aarch64, which your RPi probably is, it works with distro packages).

Comment: @MarcusMüller correct me if I'm wrong, but PK2CMD does work with PICKit2 programmers, doesn't it?

Comment: @Foad, I can chime in. I use the PK2CMD with an original Microchip PICKit2 all the time. To me it wasn't a hassle to get it running, but that depends on the experience of the user of course. It requires compilation IIRC, there's no apt/yum package you can just install.

Comment: @anrieff the more compile`ted it will be the more I will enjoy ;) can you be kind to point me towards some tutorials, or maybe you can share instructions on your blog or Github?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using SDCC compiler as it doesn't support all available microcontrollers. XC8 compiler, including PK2CMD  can be downloaded from the official Microchip website.

For **XC8** compiler, click [here](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tools-tools-and-software/mplab-xc-compilers#Downloads).

For **PK2CMD**, click [here](https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/PartNO/PG164120).

Read the accompanied documentation before attempting to do anything.